# Caseinvariant searching of part of a string in a longer string

Tags: c#, string

I have a bunch of strings for example

```
string s1 = "abc";  string s2="def"; string s3="ghi";
```

and then I have some other string:

```
string findMe = "12ABC34";
```

I want to return `True` because **case insensitive** of part of `findMe` ( which is "**abc**") does exist in s1;

I tried making a list of strings or a concatenated string out of `s1,s2,s3` and use `.Contains` or `.IndexOf`  to solve the problem but Contains didn't have a `IgnoreCase` option and `IndexOf` wasn't able to do a partial search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IndexOf()` overload which takes `ComparisonType` enumeration ans pass `OrdinalIgnoreCase` to do case insensitive comparison:

```
string s1 = "abc";
string findMe = "12ABC34";

var index = findMe.IndexOf(s1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

and use if condition on index to see if it's not **-1** then your string is found in `findMe` string.

```
if(index >= 0)
   // match found
```

As you want to match for all string together, in that case you have to create a list for the strings and then use `All()` with combination of `IndexOf()` like:

```
string s1 = "abc";  string s2="def"; string s3="ghi";
List<string> inputs = new List<string>(){s1,s2,s3};
string findMe = "12ABC34";
if(inputs.All(x=> findeMe.IndexOf(x) >=0))
{
    // s1, s2,s3 found in findMe string  
}
```

Comment: so if I have four of those strings (s1,s2,s3,s4) I should do four IndexOf?  I was hoping if I combine all those four in one string and do only on IndexOf

Comment: you cannot use all 4 together in that case you have to do it using All and create List of string  for s1,s2,s3,s4 , i have updated post as well @Bohn

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your `findMe` containing multiple patterns because you have to iterate through it, but without more constraints you end up matching "a" because you didn't specify the explicit format of how findMe contains multiple strings to find. I use [Regex.IsMatch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktzf2d23(v=vs.110).aspx) to match and ignore case. Here is my current implementation:

```
        string s1 = "abc"; string s2 = "def"; string s3 = "ghi";
        string findMe = "12ABC34";

        for (var windowSize = 1; windowSize <= findMe.Length; windowSize++)
        {
            for (var startIndex = 0; startIndex <= findMe.Length; startIndex++)
            {
                if (startIndex + windowSize <= findMe.Length)
                {
                    var findMeSubstring = findMe.Substring(startIndex, windowSize);
                    //Console.WriteLine(findMeSubstring);
                    foreach (var s in new List<string>() { s1, s2, s3 })
                    {
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(s,findMeSubstring, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                        { /*return true;*/ Console.WriteLine($"Pattern {findMeSubstring} found in string {s}."); }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Prints:

```
Pattern A found in string abc.
Pattern B found in string abc.
Pattern C found in string abc.
Pattern AB found in string abc.
Pattern BC found in string abc.
Pattern ABC found in string abc.
```